# .How do I make use of nvidia graphic card in linux?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

My HP-15 r014tx has nvidia geforce 820m installed with intel integrated.
but I notice that its not being used .
how do I install the driver ?
I searched for the answer but the answer said go to
system>administration>additional driver
(does system means system settings ) I do not find any option as administration in system settings .
and also in software and updates in additioal drivers it says no drivers currently available and the list is blank.

Comment: Use the Bumblebee driver to use Optimus: http://www.bumblebee-project.org/

Comment: how do I use the bumblebee driver ? I did the commands mention below

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same with a GTX 870m.
Here I tell you what to do :)

first install the driver for intel: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/
then install the nvidia driver, that aren't still avaible from 'aditional drivers'.
How?

## sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic

## sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

## sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

Then reboot and go with Bumblebee to change the card to your liking.

## sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable && sudo apt-get update

## sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331

This worked for me.
Regards, Vìctor.
Sorry 4 my english!!

Comment: Thank you @upiferico . I will try this and check if that works. and your English is alright :D

Comment: I did all the commands and now how do I check what is my console using right now ? each command went perfectly fine but intel graphic software tries to instal something which takes forever . maybe because intel is already uptodate ?

Comment: well, you can install this indicator to make it easier to choose the graphic card :) https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui down and then install it (making first 'install file' executable). The intel driver is secondary as ubuntu kernel is mostly already prepared to run it ok ;)